# How to customise Google plus SignInButton

Tags: android

I have tried a lot but not able to customize the Google plus Signin Button.
Please help me.

Thanks

Comment: This is policy violation if you changed that.

Answer (score 0):

First, at the layout.xml add your button:

```
<com.google.android.gms.common.SignInButton
android:id="@+id/sign_in_button"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

At the application activity, register to this button a onclicklistener :

```
findViewById(R.id.sign_in_button).setOnClickListener(this);
```

And also use this code that say to the app wait to the sign in button:

```
    /* Track whether the sign-in button has been clicked so that we know to resolve
 * all issues preventing sign-in without waiting.
 */
private boolean mSignInClicked;

/* Store the connection result from onConnectionFailed callbacks so that we can
 * resolve them when the user clicks sign-in.
 */
private ConnectionResult mConnectionResult;

/* A helper method to resolve the current ConnectionResult error. */
private void resolveSignInError() {
  if (mConnectionResult.hasResolution()) {
    try {
      mIntentInProgress = true;
      startIntentSenderForResult(mConnectionResult.getIntentSender(),
          RC_SIGN_IN, null, 0, 0, 0);
    } catch (SendIntentException e) {
      // The intent was canceled before it was sent.  Return to the default
      // state and attempt to connect to get an updated ConnectionResult.
      mIntentInProgress = false;
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
  }
}

public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
  if (!mIntentInProgress) {
    // Store the ConnectionResult so that we can use it later when the user clicks
    // 'sign-in'.
    mConnectionResult = result;

    if (mSignInClicked) {
      // The user has already clicked 'sign-in' so we attempt to resolve all
      // errors until the user is signed in, or they cancel.
      resolveSignInError();
    }
  }
}
```

And use this onclick code (indicates if it is the sign in button) :

```
    public void onClick(View view) {
  if (view.getId() == R.id.sign_in_button
    && !mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
    mSignInClicked = true;
    resolveSignInErrors();
  }
}
```

Use this code to indicate if you are already signed in:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int responseCode, Intent intent) {
  if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
    if (responseCode != RESULT_OK) {
      mSignInClicked = false;
    }

    mIntentInProgress == false;

    if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting()) {
      mGoogleApiClient.connect();
    }
  }
}
```

And add a message when you signed in successfully:

```
    @Override
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
  mSignInClicked = false;
  Toast.makeText(this, "User is connected!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Also, Read this: 
https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/sign-in